# Building wheel for mpi4py (setup.py) ... error message while installing stable_baselines

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, flow-project

After pulling the last commit of flow-project, I executed green_wave.py with python3.7.4 and then got these errors consecutively.

All these errors happened after executed **Running setup.py install for mpi4py ... error** command.

Below that, you can see the snippet of error message.

What should i do?

Thank you.

```
Ulass-MacBook-Pro:stable_baselines ulasbayram$ pip3 install stable_baselines==2.7.0
    Collecting stable_baselines==2.7.0
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/9f/bbb2122cf2ce0e5f09a33bc35d504b83c05b0896bd46d4b85687c62557f6/stable_baselines-2.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (0.10.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (4.1.0.25)
    Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=0.5.5 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (1.2.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (0.25.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (1.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: gym[atari,classic_control]>=0.10.9 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (0.13.1)
    Collecting mpi4py (from stable_baselines==2.7.0)
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/f5/a615603ce4ab7f40b65dba63759455e3da610d9a155d4d4cece1d8fd6706/mpi4py-3.0.2.tar.gz
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (1.16.4)
    Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from stable_baselines==2.7.0) (3.0.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (2.7.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (2019.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gym[atari,classic_control]>=0.10.9->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (1.3.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gym[atari,classic_control]>=0.10.9->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (1.11.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: Pillow; extra == "atari" in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gym[atari,classic_control]>=0.10.9->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (6.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: atari-py~=0.2.0; extra == "atari" in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gym[atari,classic_control]>=0.10.9->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (0.2.6)
    Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (0.10.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (2.4.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (1.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: future in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0->gym[atari,classic_control]>=0.10.9->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (0.17.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->stable_baselines==2.7.0) (41.0.1)
    Building wheels for collected packages: mpi4py
      Building wheel for mpi4py (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/0xpl6pfx3cq9x9j9dzkgl22m0000gn/T/pip-install-5qgh61eu/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/0xpl6pfx3cq9x9j9dzkgl22m0000gn/T/pip-install-5qgh61eu/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/y9/0xpl6pfx3cq9x9j9dzkgl22m0000gn/T/pip-wheel-vy49j_1r --python-tag cp37
           cwd: /private/var/folders/y9/0xpl6pfx3cq9x9j9dzkgl22m0000gn/T/pip-install-5qgh61eu/mpi4py/
      Complete output (126 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_src
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/libmpi.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/include
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      running build_clib
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      checking for library 'lmpe' ...

    .
    .
    .


    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/0xpl6pfx3cq9x9j9dzkgl22m0000gn/T/pip-install-5qgh61eu/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y9/0xpl6pfx3cq9x9j9dzkgl22m0000gn/T/pip-install-5qgh61eu/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/y9/0xpl6pfx3cq9x9j9dzkgl22m0000gn/T/pip-record-xbd7wnrr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ulasbayram/Detecon/bin/../include/site/python3.7/mpi4py Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure to follow the installation instructions for stable baselines before running the pip install? That is, did you run 'brew install cmake openmpi' before running this command? The error could be due to you not having an installation of MPI.

Comment: Oh, yes. I missed that part before installation. Thank you Eugene and sorry for this redundant question.